# wcscpy Does Not Accept TCHAR in Destination Variable

Tags: c, copy, tchar, wchar

[VS10] The aim is to copy the drive literal string into the *.dst thus

```
TCHAR *driveIDBase;
...
wcscpy_s (driveIDBase, MAX_PATH-3, L"\\\\?\\C:\\*");
```

This produces the error

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "wcscpy_s" matches
>   the argument list

Note that the ANSI version works well enough:

```
strcpy_s (driveIDBase, MAX_PATH-3, "C:\\*");
```

Supposing we try the obvious workaround:

strcpy_s (driveIDBase, MAX_PATH-3, "\\?\C:\");

can we call the cast *(wchar_t *) driveIDBase* reliable? That is, WIN32_FIND_DATAW will interpret that string as "C:\"?

Also what is meant by this quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#win32_file_namespaces)?

> The "\\?\" prefix turns off automatic expansion of the path string,

Comment: Works fine for me (VS2015). `TCHAR` depends on the Character Set selection in the project. Is it set to Unicode?

Comment: @Bo It's MBCS. Heh, changing to Unicode gets heaps of "incompatible" type errors in the code- I'll want to look at that. Have the ISO for 2015 right here. Worth a shot?

Comment: VS2015 will not change anything here. `TCHAR` is either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on that setting. If you write new software, you can just use wchar_t and skip the TCHAR thingy. That was introduced to ease writing code for both Windows 95 and Windows NT. Not something we do much nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worth noting the Stack Overflow definition of TCHAR:

> A #define for either char or wchar_t, used for porting ancient windows
>   applications.

The code being assembled is not an ancient port, albeit the initial reason for including it in the current project was that it was recommended (in older threads) for the purposes of conversion in certain API functions. 
Due to the phase out of MBCS, building a project these days is preferable in Unicode as Bo suggests above, which renders the usage of the TCHAR macro redundant.
As for the second part of the question, suppose a wide char directory is created thus:

```
%USERPROFILE%\This Is A SubDirectory of %USERPROFILE% Not C-Colon-Backslash-Users-Backslash-MyUserName-- Being the Expanded Directory Path We Intended to Use
```

We note that under \\?\ the given subdirectory would not be created in "C:\Users\MyUserName". In fact it could not in most cases, as C:\Users would never have been created with a \\?\ prefix in the first instance.

Concluding this part of the answer with another question:
 Regarding another statement from the same page in MSDN which states:

> The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because the
>   "\\?\" prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the system at run
>   time, and this expansion applies to the total length,

is the expansion at run time not automatic?